# Rename a mapped network drive

Tags: networking, command-line, command, mapping, command-prompt

I have mapped a network drive to my computer. Once it is successful, it will appear on my computer's windows explorer like this Client (\192.168.1.100)(Z:)
But I want to rename it and show only Client(Z:) on my explorer.
I have used

```
label z: newname
```

command using command prompt, but it shows a message that

```
Access Denied as you dont have sufficient privileges. You have to invoke this utility running in elevated mode.
```

Answer (score 1):

your question leaves some things open:

- what windows version?
- are you a local admin?
- are you running as admin?

I can do this by simply right clicking and use rename or by pressing F2 and renaming. If you want to use the command line i suspect you need to right click the command line and "Run as administrator" if your already running the command line as administrator i don't know.

Comment: I tried running as admin the cmd, but it says "Parameters not compatible". BTW, the drive that I want to rename is a mapped drive..

Comment: @InformationTechnology Did you find an answer?